# Use Jersey 2 from Spring XD module?

Tags: spring-xd

I have an issue packing Jersey 2 client as part of Batch Job Module with Spring XD. 
Will this be at all possible to make XD working with Jersey 2 jars from module instead of the one supplied by runtime?
The 1.2 Release shipped with jersey-*-1.9 jars. 
The module I am trying to deploy has Jersey 2 jars in its /lib directory.
Here is some jars packaged with module:

```
lib/oauth1-client-2.19.jar   OK
lib/oauth1-signature-2.19.jar   OK
lib/jersey-media-json-jackson-2.19.jar   OK
lib/jersey-common-2.19.jar   OK
lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar   OK
lib/jersey-client-2.19.jar   OK
```

At module deploy step Jersy2 calls external REST Service:

`WebTarget target = client.target(theRESTAPIEndpoint);
        String responseString = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);`

The following Exception is seen in XD log file:

`2015-07-27T15:48:01-0400 1.2.0.RELEASE ERROR DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step helloSpringXDStep in job helloSpringXD2
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/home//projects/poc/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class to jar:file:/home//projects/poc/spring-xd-1.2.0.RELEASE/xd/custom-modules/job/myjob2.jar!/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:146) ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120) ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:95) ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119) ~[jersey-core-1.9.jar:1.9]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.(JerseyWebTarget.java:71) ~[jersey-client-2.19.jar!/:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:211) ~[jersey-client-2.19.jar!/:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:72) ~[jersey-client-2.19.jar!/:na]`

Answer (score 0):

If you need 2.0.1 instead of 1.9, try replacing the libs in xd/lib (but no guarantees that it will work).

Comment: I have replaced jersey-*1.9 jars with jersey-*2.19 in xd/lib as well as deleted xd/lib/hadoop26/jersey-<*>-1.9.jar. The REST calls to external web services  started working.  What part Container/Admin functionality may be impacted by these changes?